# matplotlib — are there actual PyPlot objects that interact with Basemap objects?

Tags: matplotlib-basemap

Looking at the [Basemap docs](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html), I can see how a Basemap object is instantiated and overlaid with content:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
map = Basemap(projection='ortho',lat_0=45,lon_0=-100,resolution='l')
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)
...
```

The object is named `map` and various Basemap methods act on it. But I can't understand how, later in the same code, PyPlot (imported as `plt`) behaves. There seems to be no distinct PyPlot object, and the calls to the PyPlot module never mention `map`:

```
# make up some data on a regular lat/lon grid.
nlats = 73; nlons = 145; delta = 2.*np.pi/(nlons-1)
lats = (0.5*np.pi-delta*np.indices((nlats,nlons))[0,:,:])
lons = (delta*np.indices((nlats,nlons))[1,:,:])
wave = 0.75*(np.sin(2.*lats)**8*np.cos(4.*lons))
mean = 0.5*np.cos(2.*lats)*((np.sin(2.*lats))**2 + 2.)
# compute native map projection coordinates of lat/lon grid.
x, y = map(lons*180./np.pi, lats*180./np.pi)
# contour data over the map.
cs = map.contour(x,y,wave+mean,15,linewidths=1.5)
plt.title('contour lines over filled continent background')
plt.show()
```

How and where does PyPlot interact with the `map` object?

Also, in the third line of code from the bottom, why is variable `cs` being assigned, since it isn't actually used elsewhere in the code? I see no difference in the output with `cs =` removed.

Answer (score 0):

`pyplot` is just an interface to various `matplotlib` modules. For example, `plt.plot()` finds the current `Axes` object (let's call it `ax`) and the uses the `ax.plot()` method to do the drawing.

In general, operating on the `Axes`, or in this case `Basemap` objects directly is the greatly preferred style.